# Trying to change multiple variables with try / except function

Tags: python, exception, while-loop, global-variables, try-catch

```
def tryexcept(variable,range1,range2):
    while variable not in range(range1,range2):
        try:
            if variable not in range(range1,range2):
                variable = int(input("Enter your decision \033[95m(1)\033[0m or \033[95m(2)\033[0m"))
                # Making the options stand out with \033[95m for error prevention, plus it looks nice
        except:
            print("Not valid please enter an intiger \033[95m(1 or 2)\033[0m")

menu_option = 0

tryexcept(menu_option,1,3)
```

I have tried global variables and changing the order the variables are defined

Comment: What does your function return?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted?

```
def tryexcept(variable,range1,range2):
    while variable not in range(range1,range2):
        try:
            if variable not in range(range1,range2):
                variable = int(input("Enter your decision \033[95m(1)\033[0m or \033[95m(2)\033[0m"))
            # Making the options stand out with \033[95m for error prevention, plus it looks nice
        except:
            print("Not valid please enter an intiger \033[95m(1 or 2)\033[0m")
# Returns the variable once the loop is finished
    return variable


menu_option = 0

# Sets menu_option to the return value
menu_option = tryexcept(menu_option,1,3)
```